# Restores a difficult digraph

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks

I want to reconstruct this picture,like this:

[image]

I have do some work,this is my code

```mathematica
u = {1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4};
v = {3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2};

weight = {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0};

edge = {
   EdgeWeight -> weight,
   EdgeStyle -> {RGBColor["#4472c7"]
     , Thick},
   EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeWeight", 0.5]};
    
vertex = {
   VertexStyle -> {_ -> White,
     Alternatives @@ {1} -> RGBColor["#538234"],
     Alternatives @@ {2, 3} -> RGBColor["#4473c3"],
     Alternatives @@ {4} -> RGBColor["#ed7d31"]
     },
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
   VertexLabelStyle -> {
     Alternatives @@ Range@4 -> 
      Directive[30, White, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]
     },
   VertexSize -> Large};

Graph[
  MapThread[DirectedEdge[#1, #2] &, {u, v}],
  edge,
  vertex,
  GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", 
    "VertexPartition" -> {1, 2, 1}}
  ] // SetProperty[#, 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
    Thread[VertexList[#] -> ({1.3, 1} # & /@ 
        ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}][GraphEmbedding[#]])]] &
```

get this

[image]

By comparing two images:

[image]

My image is:

1.Edge is **bend**

2.Vertex color is more **dim**

I didn't know what to do next. Help me

Comment: If all you want is the picture, then just use a vector graphics tool (e.g. InkScape, or PowerPoint in a pinch): it will be a lot less work!

Comment: Add `BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[]` as `Graph` option to remove black borders from vertices and `EdgeShapeFunction -> ({ Arrow[#1, .35]} &)` to make edges straight (might need change to touch the vertices).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set up custom edge function:

```
myEdge[s_ : .25, offset_ : .04][coords_, _[a_, b_]] :=
 Block[{x = coords[[1]], y = coords[[-1]], normal},
  normal = Normalize[{-1, 1} Reverse[y - x]];
  Arrow[{coords[[1]] + offset normal, coords[[-1]] + offset normal}, 
   s]]
```

set EdgeForm might help for color:

```
u = {1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4};
v = {3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2};

weight = {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0};

edge = {EdgeWeight -> weight, 
   EdgeStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[{68, 115, 193, 255}/255], Thick], 
   EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeWeight", 0.5]};

vertex = {VertexStyle -> {_ -> White, 
     Alternatives @@ {1} -> 
      Directive[EdgeForm[RGBColor["#538234"]], RGBColor["#538234"]], 
     Alternatives @@ {2, 3} -> 
      Directive[EdgeForm[RGBColor["#4473c3"]], RGBColor["#4473c3"]], 
     Alternatives @@ {4} -> 
      Directive[EdgeForm[RGBColor["#ed7d31"]], RGBColor["#ed7d31"]]}, 
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
   VertexLabelStyle -> {Alternatives @@ Range@4 -> 
      Directive[30, White, Bold, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"]}, 
   VertexSize -> Large};

Graph[MapThread[DirectedEdge[#1, #2] &, {u, v}], edge, vertex, 
  GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", 
    "VertexPartition" -> {1, 2, 1}}, EdgeShapeFunction -> myEdge[]] //
  SetProperty[#, 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
    Thread[VertexList[#] -> ({1.3, 1} # & /@ 
        ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}][GraphEmbedding[#]])]] &
```

Answer (score 5):

Color appearance is influenced by what is around. For example, the vertices have thick edges of different colors, which I tried to reproduced below. I changed to color of the edges to match the target. If the font needs to be reproduced, there are better options than Times New Roman. Below I use a font downloaded from Google Fonts (Noto Serif). The arrows are made opaque to match the target, but both ends point to the center of the vertices (see halmir's answer to correct that).

```
u = {1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4};
v = {3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2};

weight = {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0};

edge = {EdgeWeight -> weight, EdgeStyle -> RGBColor["#4a74c1ff"], 
   EdgeLabels -> Placed["EdgeWeight", 0.5]};

vertex = {VertexStyle -> {_ -> White,
     Alternatives @@ {1} -> 
      Directive[RGBColor["#538234"], 
       EdgeForm[{Thick, RGBColor["#556f40"]}]],
     Alternatives @@ {2, 3} -> 
      Directive[RGBColor["#4473c3"], 
       EdgeForm[{Thick, RGBColor["#53739c"]}]],
     Alternatives @@ {4} -> 
      Directive[RGBColor["#ed7d31"], 
       EdgeForm[{Thick, RGBColor["#b58549"]}]]},
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
   VertexLabelStyle -> (Alternatives @@ Range@4 -> 
      Directive[72, White, Bold, FontFamily -> "Noto Serif"]), 
   VertexSize -> Large};

Graph[MapThread[DirectedEdge[#1, #2] &, {u, v}], edge, vertex, 
  GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", 
    "VertexPartition" -> {1, 2, 1}}, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Arrow[#1, 0.25]} &)] // 
 SetProperty[#, 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
    Thread[
     VertexList[#] -> ({1.3, 1} # & /@ 
        ReflectionTransform[{0, 1}][GraphEmbedding[#]])]] &
```

[image]